# EntityFramework mapping for joining 2 tables via a mapping table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, poco

Hopefully someone can point me where I'm going wrong.

SQL: (Simple representation of SQL Tables)

```
Item { ID, Name}
Message { ID, Title }
ItemMessages { ItemID, MessageID }
```

Objects: (Simple representation of C# POCO Objects)

```
Item { ID, Name, Messages }
Message { ID, Title, Item }
```

This is technically speaking a Many to one (a message can have only one Item, but an item can have multiple messages).

via the EF model mapping I have this for the Item.

```
HasMany(i => i.Messages).WithOptional(m => m.Item).Map(m => { m.ToTable("ItemMessages"); m.MapKey("MessageID") });
```

Unfortunately this does not work though, no matter how I configure it.
Many to many relations work fine as it lets me define the left and right key but I need to have it so that the Messages collection in Item and the Item object in message all populate appropriately.

Anyone able to spot where I am going wrong here?